# Intel XDK iOS build produce zero sized ipa files

Tags: ios, intel, intel-xdk

I'm trying to make this build system to work.. I've managed to create and build several projects, everything is cool all the way from building to running on the iPhone. But at some point today, the XDK started to produce zero sized ipa files and the links it sends by email to download the binaries are broken. No errors, no warnings. The android files are produced fine and downloadable, yet iOS files are zero sized. But it was OK just few minutes ago, nothing changed on my side..

Kind of show stopper to me. Does anyone use Intel XDK for practical things? How stable is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with the build system that has been resolved.